# Form Won't Pass Value Pair In Get Request Url After Submission

Tags: laravel, http, curl, get

I'm familiarizing myself with API's Get & Post Request in Laravel. I have a form where an admin can send Points to an external API. Unfortunately, in the documentation the request has to be a GET request and the data which is being submitted has to append to the url
ie: myurl.com/my-end-point?platform_id=value&auth=value...

The issue is, whenever i fill the form and submit the url remains the same:
ie: myurl.com/my-end-point?platform_id=platform_id&auth=auth...

It does not pass the data in the get request.

Controller

```
public function sendCpdPoints(Request $request)
{
$response = Http::asForm()->get('myurl.com/my-end-point', [
            'platform_id' => 'platform_id',
            'auth' => 'auth',
            'cpd_id' => 'cpd_id',
            'registration_number' => 'registration_number',
            'certificate' => 'certificate',
]);

dd($response);

}
```

View (Blade)

```
<form action="{{url('admin/rewards/points/manual_update/dashboard/store/participants-points') }}" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Platform Id</label>
                            <input type="text" name="platform_id" id='platform_id' class="form-control" value="123" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Authentication Key</label>
                            <input type="text" name="auth" id='auth' class="form-control" value="123456789" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Cpd Id</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cpd_id" id='cpd_id' class="form-control" placeholder=".ie 587">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Registration Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="registration_number" id='registration_number' class="form-control" placeholder=".ie MDC/PA/RNXXXX">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Certificate Serial Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="certificate" id='certificate' class="form-control" placeholder=".ie 2022-03/001">
                        </div>
                        <button type="send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Help is greatly appreciated. As i really want to get better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value from the form . You can use `$request->` from the request facade

You can try this

```
 public function sendCpdPoints(Request $request)
 {
   $response = Http::asForm()->get('myurl.com/my-end-point', [
        'platform_id' =>  $request->platform_id,
        'auth' => $request->auth,
        'cpd_id' => $request->cpd_id,
        'registration_number' => $request->registration_number,
        'certificate' => $request->certificate,
  ]);

  dd($response);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. It did the trick. Is it possible to store a copy of the request in the database ?. Ps. I would love to be mentored.

Comment: Yes you can save your request in your database before sending it to the endpoint.
There are different ways of storing data in the database in Laravel.



    $model = new Mymodel();
    $model-> platform_id = $request-> platform_id;
    $model->auth = $request->auth;
   $model-> cpd_id = $request-> cpd_id;
    $model->save();

Visit Laravel documentation for more details.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand. Does your backend that handles the request call an external API? If that's the case, the problem is that you're passing strings as an argument. To retrieve the form values try something like:
$request->auth or
$request->get('auth')

If this is not the case, and you simply want to get the form data in your backend, I advise you to do it with JS using AJAX. You can use Fetch or install an external lib like axios to do this.

NOTE: the type of your submit button is incorrect, change it to type="submit"
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: Yes my backend handles the request call to the External API.